# Using a disabled button

Tags: vb.net

If I have two buttons, one to start a song being played and one to stop it. The start button has enabled set to true and the stop button is enabled to false. What I want to happen is the stop button to only become active when the start button is pressed. I was thinking of putting stopMusicButton.enabled(True) within the start method, but this doesnt seem to work :( Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
Public Sub OnStartClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startMusicButton.Click
  startMusicButton.Enabled = False
  stopMusicButton.Enabled = True
  ' Play the Music

End Sub

Public Sub OnStopClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles stopMusicButton.Click
  startMusicButton.Enabled = True
  stopMusicButton.Enabled = False
  ' Stop the Music
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works a treat. I will accept your answer later have to shoot on.

Answer (score 2):

Use JaredPar's suggestion, OR use a single button:

```
    Private Sub btnMusic_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMusic.Click

    If btnMusic.Text = "Start" Then
        btnMusic.Text = "Stop"
        'play music
    Else
        btnMusic.Text = "Start"
        'stop music
    End If
End Sub
```